# Нахождение номера элемента с которого два списка становятся равны

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, arraylist

Есть два списка, например:

```
a = [0,1,2,4,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = [2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,9,9]
```

Они не обязательно равны по длине. Начиная с какого-то элемента списки равны. В данном пример они равны начиная с 4 элемента, но подряд только в 4 последующих, после этого могут быть не равны (но больше равенства элементов не будет нигде, равенство может встретится только в одном куске списка). Надо вернуть номер элемента с которого начинается равенство.
Написал код, но что-то не могу дотянуть его, все время выскакивают разные ошибки, ну и некрасивый в целом получается. Причем решить надо именно в рамках обычных списков, а не numpy и не используя дополнительных библиотек с помощью бинарного поиска.

```
min_l = min(len(a),len(b))
a = a[:min_l]
b = b[:min_l]
def foo(a,b):
    lenght = len(a)
    i=0
    while lenght!=1:
        if len(a)%2 == 1:
            lenght = (lenght + 1) / 2
        else:
            lenght = (lenght) / 2
        lenght = int(lenght)    
        i += int(1/2 * lenght + lenght%2)   
        if a[lenght] == b[lenght] and a[lenght-1] != b[lenght-1]:
            return lenght
            print('shag 1', lenght, i)
        if a[lenght] == b[lenght] and a[int(i/2)] == b[int(i/2)]:
            print('shag 2', lenght, i)
            foo(a[:i+1],b[:i+1])
        if a[lenght] == b[lenght] and a[int(i/2)] != b[int(i/2)]:
            print('shag 3', lenght, i)
            foo(a[:i+int(i/2 + i%2)+1],b[:i+int(i/2 + i%2)+1])    
        if a[lenght-1] != b[lenght-1] and a[lenght] == b[lenght]:
            print('shag 4', lenght, i)
            return lenght+1
        else:
            foo(a[:(i+int(i/2))],b[:(i+int(i/2))])
```

Comment: Вообще это обычная задача поиска максимальной общей подпоследовательности.

Answer (score 3):

Если просто надо вернуть индекс первой пары совпадающих чисел:

```
from operator import eq

a = [0,1,2,4,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = [2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,9,9]

for n, pair in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    if eq(*pair):
        print(n)  # 4
        break
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Но это задание мне дали на собеседовании при приеме на работе и сказали, что нельзя пользоваться дополнительными библиотеками. Кроме того отмели мое решение с помощью простого перебора и использования while. Надо решить именно бинарным делением.

Comment: @RudolfMorkovskyi, тут не используются дополнительные библиотеки. Что такое бинарное деление (в информатике)?

Comment: Под бинарным делением вероятно имеется ввиду двоичный поиск ..

Comment: @Kromster, тоже так подумал. Но не понятно, какое это имеет отношение к данной задаче, где сортировка не подразумевается.

Comment: Список делится пополам, смотрим есть ли равные элементы, если есть, опять делим пополам налево, есть нет, делим налево и направо пополам, пока не найдем равный

Comment: @mkkik мне тоже это кажется странным советом, но по крайней мере *такой* термин, в отличии от бинарного деления, существует и хоть как-то может быть притянут за уши.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,l in enumerate(a):
    if l == b[i]: break
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот я сделал решение, но только оно с использованием numpy, а надо без numpy:

```
def foo(a, b):
lower = 0
upper = len(a)
while lower != upper:
    lenght = (lower + upper) // 2    
    if a[lenght] == b[lenght]:
        return lenght - sum(np.array(a[:lenght]) == np.array(b[:lenght]))
    elif a[lenght] != b[lenght] and sum(np.array(a[:lenght+1]) == np.array(b[:lenght+1]))>0:
        upper = lenght
    else:
        lower = lenght + 1
return None
```

Вот решил без numpy, но только на одну сторону:

Решил также без циклов, но только на одну сторону:

```
def foo_4(a, b):
    lower = 0
    upper = len(a)
    while lower != upper:
        lenght = (lower + upper) // 2
        if lenght == 0 and a[lenght] == b[lenght]:
            return lenght
        if a[lenght] == b[lenght] and a[lenght-1] != b[lenght-1]:
            return lenght
        elif a[lenght] != b[lenght]:
            lower = lenght + 1
    return None
```

А вот с numpy, и в одну строчку:

```
def foo_3(a,b):
    return np.where((a - b) == 0)[0][0]
```

Но как решить без numpy и с условием прерывания списка, непонятно

Comment: `upper = len(a)`, вы же говорили в вопросе, что списки могут быть разной длины. Приведет к выходу за пределы массива, если `len(b) < len(a)`.

Comment: Да, надо вначале добавить:

       len_min = min(len(a), len(b))
       a = a[:len_min]

       b = b[:len_min]

Comment: А если пересечение окажется в отсеченной части более длинного списка? Пример: `a, b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1]`.

Comment: Такого не может быть, потому должны быть равны элементы стоящие на одних и тех же индексах. Т.е. в этом пример 0 элемент из списка а не равен 0 элементу из списка b

Comment: Да, с отсечением все верно.